# How to destroy an empty Quarry?

Tags: banished

How can I destroy a Quarry where no Stonecutter is working anymore (0% of stones remaining)?

Can I reuse this footprint for something else, like a fish pond or a stock pile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot reuse the land. The quarry leaves behind a permanent large hole in the ground. The tooltip already tells you this:

[image: Quarry [8] Used to mine stone from the ground.]

> #### Quarry [8]
>
> Used to mine stone from the ground.
> Quarries **cannot be removed once placed.**

Answer (score 4):

You CAN remove the building on the quarry, which will not reduce the footprint of the quarry, but it will return you some of the building materials. Otherwise, the footprint is permanently lost.